# Reading and writing multiple files simultaneously using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are developing one application which will read multiple files & write multiple files i.e. one output file for one input file (name of output file must be same as input file).
MultiResourceItemReader can read multiple files but not simultaneously, which is a performance bottleneck for us. Spring batch provides multithreading support for this but again many threads will read the same file & try to write it. Since output file name must be same as Input file name, we can't use that option too.

Now I am looking for one more possibility, if I can create 'n' threads to read & write 'n' files. But I am not sure how to integrate this logic with Spring Batch framework.

Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since MultiResourceItemReader doesn't meet your performance needs you may take a closer look at [parallel processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html), which you already mentioned is a desirable option. I don't think many threads will read the same file and try to write it when running multi-threaded, if configured correctly.

Rather than taking the typical chunk-oriented approach you could create a tasklet-orient step that is partitioned (multi-threaded).  The tasklet class would be the main driver, delegating calls to a reader and a writer.

The general flow would be something like this:

1. Retrieve the names of all the files that need to be read in/written out (via some service class) and save them to the execution context within an implementation of [Partitioner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html).

   ```
   public class filePartitioner implements Partitioner {

   @Override
   public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
       Map<String, Path> filesToProcess = this.service.getFilesToProcess(directory); // this is just sudo-ish code but maybe you inject the directory you'll be targeting into this class
       Map<String, ExecutionContext> execCtxs = new HashMap<>();
       for(Entry<String, Path> entry : filesToProcess.entrySet()) {
           ExecutionContext execCtx = new ExecutionContext();
           execCtx.put("file", entry.getValue());
           execCtxs.put(entry.getKey(), execCtx);  
       }

       return execCtxs;
   }

   // injected
   public void setServiceClass(ServiceClass service) {
       this.service = service;
   }
   }
   ```

   a. For the .getFilesToProcess() method you just need something that returns all of the files in the designated directory because you need to eventually know what is to be read and the name of the file that is to be written.  Obviously there are several ways to go about this, such as...

   ```
   public Map<String, Path> getFilesToProcess(String directory) {
       Map<String, Path> filesToProcess = new HashMap<String, Path>();
       File directoryFile = new File(directory); // where directory is where you intend to read from
       this.generateFileList(filesToProcess, directoryFile, directory);

   private void generateFileList(Map<String, Path> fileList, File node, String directory) {
       // traverse directory and get files, adding to file list.

       if(node.isFile()) {
           String file = node.getAbsoluteFile().toString().substring(directory.length() + 1, node.toString().length());
           fileList.put(file, directory);
   }

       if(node.isDirectory()) {
           String[] files = node.list();
           for(String filename : files) {
               this.generateFileList(fileList, new File(node, filename), directory);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You'll need to create a tasklet, which will pull file names from the execution context and pass them to some injected class that will read in the file and write it out (custom ItemReaders and ItemWriters may be necessary).
3. The rest of the work would be in configuration, which should be fairly straight forward.  It is in the configuration of the Partitioner where you can set your grid size, which could even be done dynamically using SpEL if you really intend to create n threads for n files.  I would bet a fixed number of threads running across n files would show significant improvement in performance but you'll be able to determine that for yourself.

Hope this helps.